# how to make an image jump inside canvas

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming world. I am currently trying to make a skateboard game where there will be a character just jumping when a key is pressed and the background image will move inside the canvas. My problem is I am unable to make the character jump and set up an image as background. It would be great if somebody kindly could tell me how.
Thanks in Advance

link:  http://jsbin.com/colohuzixe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You should include your code here as links rot and users shouldnt have to go to an external site to see the code. If your code it to long for users to look through quickly read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am new here sir so I know very little about how to use this website.

Comment: I tried to do that but it says the codes have some errors but I don't know how to fix them.